# Check the dimensions of an img with RSpec/Capybara?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara

I'm trying to test the dimensions of an img tag without explicit `height` and `width` attributes, but I'm not sure how to do that exactly.

```
subject { page }

describe "profile page" do
  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
  before { visit user_path(user) }

  describe "gravatar image" do
    it "should exist" do
      expect(page.first(".gravatar")).not_to be nil
    end

    it "should be 50x50" do
      gravatar = page.first(".gravatar")
      expect(gravatar[:height]).to eq(50)
      expect(gravatar[:width]).to eq(50)
    end
  end
end
```

The test for existence works, but the dimension test tells me that the attributes `height` and `width` are `nil`, which I can sort of understand because I never set them explicitly. But how do I get the actual height/width of an image?

Answer (score 3):

You can use a combination of `evaluate_script` and client side javascript to get that result:

```
page.evaluate_script("$('img')[0].clientHeight")
```

This would require that your test is executed via a JS runtime like poltergeist etc.

Comment: I tried installing poltergeist but could never get it to work properly. I couldn't get jquery to load so I tried using `document.findElementsByClassName(".gravatar")` but it always returned nil. I'll update to show exactly what I did.

Comment: Thanks! This is what I needed: `page.evaluate_script("$(\"img[name='image_name.png']\")[0].clientHeight")`